# How do I get the SelectedValue of a ComboBox from code?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe3, livebindings

I am trying to build something like a `TLookupComboBox` using LiveBindings.

I have placed a normal `TComboBox` on a VCL form. I also have a data set with some rows that have the two fields `id` and `text`.

Then I used the LiveBindings editor to create a `TBindSourceDB` and a `TBindingsList`.

There is just one binding in it:

```
object BindingsList1: TBindingsList
  Methods = <>
  OutputConverters = <>
  UseAppManager = True
  Left = 244
  Top = 229
  object LinkFillControlToField1: TLinkFillControlToField
    Category = 'Quick Bindings'
    Control = ComboBox1
    Track = True
    FillDataSource = BindSourceDB1
    FillValueFieldName = 'id'
    FillDisplayFieldName = 'text'
    AutoFill = True
    BufferCount = -1
    FillExpressions = <>
  end
end
```

As you can see I have different fields for `FillValueFieldName` and `FillDisplayFieldName`.

The LiveBindings designer looks like this:

[image: BindSourceDB1 connected to ComboBox1]

The ComboBox is filled with the values from the field `text`, so I think I set it up correctly.

How can I get the `SelectedValue` from code?

I could visually bind the value to a `TLabel` and then I could read the `TLabel.Caption`, but surely there is an easier way?

PS: I do not want to store the value in the DB, otherwise I would just use a `TDBLookupComboBox`.

**Edit:** I have tried to use a `TPrototypeBindSource`, but that has no obvious way to access the fields from code. I have also tried to use a second `TBindSourceDB` together with a `TClientDataSet` which works, but that feels like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the selected value via the corresponding `TLinkFillControlToField`:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
    SelectedValue: Integer;
begin
    if TryStrToInt(LinkFillControlToField1.BindList.GetSelectedValue.AsString, SelectedValue) then
      DoSomethingWith(SelectedValue);
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you. you can add a global variable named `selectedIndex`, then double click on the combo box. it will bring the `ComboBoxChange` event. Then write the code below:

```
selectedIndex := combobox1.ItemIndex;
```