# Delphi Firemonkey ComboBox insert in AdoTable

Tags: delphi, combobox, firemonkey

So, I've been using LiveBindings between two tables at a combobox to get the Id and Description of a foreign key(with the Item.LookupData and Item.text properties) and assign the key to a field in another table with the SelectedValue propertie. This is working fine i guess but i'm using custom dbnavigator controls to make a "register form".
I'm using methods like this to make the inserts: `adotablealuno.FieldValues['Nome']:=editnomeAluno.Text;`

But I'cant find how to use the combobox in this way, i've already tried the ItemIndex and Selected properties, but none of this work (I'm using a Access DB btw). How can I use my foreign key in ComboBox for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I was already stating this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31453018/5043424) and there was no good answer for a long time. I found a way out that I am currently using. At least I know that I'll get reliable data. 
You need to handle `OnFillingListItem` event of the `LinkFillControlToField` link in alike way and store id number in `ComboBox` Items. I use `Tag` property for this purpose though it is not actually good.

```
procedure TForm1.LinkFillControlToField1FillingListItem(Sender: TObject;
  const AEditor: IBindListEditorItem);
begin
  (AEditor.CurrentObject as TListBoxItem).Tag :=
    YourLookuptable.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
end;
```

And then fetch the item id from ListBox1.Selected.Tag. The text value can be accessed via `ComboBox1.Selected.Text`.

**Appended.**

You make an alike `LinkFillControlToField` link. [image]

Then you select this **link** and create an `OnFillingListItem` event handler to the link (select events tab in the Object Inspector and double click on `OnFillingListItem` ComboBox). The event handler (empty procedure) will appear. It will be given a name like `TForm1.LinkFillControlToField1FillingListItem(...` Then you write the code setting the id property to the items' Tags.

Comment: I'll try this. I just don't get from which control this is. I put this in the combobox or the binding?

Comment: @GuilhermeRaguzzoni I have appended my answer, however, I suppose that you have got it already.

Comment: Yes, I got that already, however, you made a great addition =)