# Delphi Berlin FMX Combobox Values via LiveBindings

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, livebindings

I have a `combobox` with the following manually entered values: `Active`, `Inactive`. However I want to save only values `A` or `I` in my database. How do I do this via `livebindings`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FillDataSource = BindSourceDB1
FillValueFieldName = 'value' // A and I would be in this field
FillDisplayFieldName = 'name' // Active and Inactive would be in this field`

[How to get Item.LookupData and SelectedValue (as integer) of an FMX TComboBox at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453018/how-to-get-item-lookupdata-and-selectedvalue-as-integer-of-an-fmx-tcombobox-at)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the data in my combobox does not come from a data source, I add them manually when the form is created. Using ComboBox.Items.Add ('').

Comment: In that case I would recommend you create a TFDMemTable and put your manual items in the TFDMemTable. Then you can bind it to the FillDataSource.